# complex infinity

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, special-functions, bessel-functions

Hi I am interested in a question regarding complex infinities.
For example, consider the function

$$
q(x)=\frac{1}{x}\sqrt{i-1},\quad x\in \mathbb{R}
$$
where $i=\sqrt{-1}$.  Now let's take the limit of $q(x)$ as $x\to 0$, (from now on I will use $q(x)\equiv q$),
$$
\lim_{x\to 0} q=\lim_{x\to 0}\left( \frac{1}{x}\sqrt{i-1}\right).
$$
Is it appropriate to say
$$
\lim_{x\to 0} q\to \infty?
$$
What is the exact way to define the complex infinity?  I am interested because I am taking a limit of 
$$
\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{qJ'_1(q)}{J_1(q)}
$$
however I am unsure as to how to take the limit since I do not know how to deal with the complex infinities.  If I understand how to deal with the complex infinity, I will be able to expand the Bessel functions as usual and then be able to take the limit.  Thanks!

Also, in case you are interested
$$
J'_1(q)=\frac{1}{2}(J_0(q)-J_2(q))
$$

Comment: why do you need to know anything about complex infinities if your limit is finite and is simply $1$?

Comment: I would rather write down $\sqrt{-1+i}\infty$, this incorporates the direction of the "$\infty$". The complex domain is 2D. Writing down a 1D expression makes no sense.

Comment: @NikolayGromov which limit is equal to 1?  The one involving Bessel functions? $$
\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{qJ'_1(q)}{J_1(q)}=1?
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use L'Hôpital's rule to get $1$ immediately.
Seee https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule

Comment: Are you sure your answer is correct?

Comment: yes absolutely!

Comment: do you mean $$
\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{qJ'_1(q)}{J_1(q)}=1?
$$

Comment: no, this one $$ \lim_{q\to 0}\frac{q J'_1(q)}{J_1(q)}=1$$

Comment: I don't think your answer is correct perhaps you can  provide a proof. Thank you

Comment: if you really want $x\to 0$ i.e. $q\to \infty$ the limit does not exist. Expansion in small $x$ is the following (for real positive small $x$)
$$
\frac{\sqrt{-1+i}}{x}-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{3 x}{8
   \sqrt{-1+i}}+\left(-\frac{3}{16}-\frac{3 i}{16}\right) x^2+\dots
$$

Comment: I see, thank you very much for your help on multiple problems!